# Подскажите в чем может быть проблема в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь отправить `GET` запрос на сервер, но сервер выводит ошибки:

> GET http://localhost:8000/prices net::ERR_ABORTED 422 (Unprocessable
> Entity)
>
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
> at App.js:30
> let path = [dateFrom, dateTo,ticker, code, token]

```
const raw = JSON.stringify({path: `${path}`});
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    head: raw,
    //redirect: 'follow',
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/${type}`, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setData(json))
},[type])
```

Где в `raw` передаются данные на сервер. Все ли правильно в синтаксисе? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ path })`. Что такое `head`?

Comment: Так как body нет в useEffect передаю JSON в head, возможно тут ошибка?

Comment: больше похоже, что ошибка происходит на сервере, поэтому надо смотреть серверный код, какие данные туда приходят и как разбирается запрос.